# Custom ItemsControl Template: Item Property Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, itemscontrol

I am trying to create custom `ItemsControl`, that displays a list of buttons (for practice sake), quite simple as below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>


    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to make it dynamic in the sense that I can bind a list of Objects to the `ItemsSource` and display a specified property from those objects as the text to display in the button. Similar to how `DisplayMemberPath` works in a `ComboBox` (when specifying a string property to display), however I have read that you cannot use both `ItemTemplate` and `DisplayMemberPath` at the same time? So how could I implement a similar property in my case.

Comment: I'm using a Custom Control because I am going to develop it into something further, this is just the base.

Comment: I think you could create a dependency property on your Custom Control, bind it to the button in the ItemTemplate. the instance then assign it with the property name

Comment: Yea after a bit of thought I about hiding the original DisplayMemberPath, and creating so it appears to behave like the original DisplayMemberPath.